# Cordova Splash Screen Plugin

Tags: android, ios, cordova, splash-screen

I'm trying to add a splash screen to my Cordova App using the plugin below:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/com.peerio.cordova.plugin.splashscreen

I'm at the point where I've copied across the example config.xml code and changed the src filepath to the image I want to use. It mentions:

`Please notice that the value of the "src" attribute is relative to the project directory and not to the www directory. You can name the source image whatever you like. The internal name in the app is determined by Cordova.`

So based on that I would believe that my src should be
`/www/img/splash.jpg` ?

No matter what I change it to though it always shows the Cordova logo. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try :

```
<splash src="www/img/splash.jpg" density="land-hdpi"/>
```

without the leading `/` ?

**Edit**

You are showing your `browser` platform. You should look in `platforms/android/res` for Android (if you are doing `cordova build android`).

If you want the browser platform, in the documentation there is a specific [Browser quirk](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen#browser-quirks). So by default, the image src is located in `"/img/logo.png"` in the `platforms/browser` folder. You must set:

```
<platform name="browser">
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="/images/browser/splashscreen.jpg" />
</platform>
```

Comment: I imagine the `config.xml` file at the root of your project ? as is your `www` folder ?

Comment: Did you do a fresh clean + build ? What is the content of your generated res/drawable folders ? do you see your image there ?

Comment: yes I did. This is the first thing I'm attempting to do. I've added screenshots of the folder structure as an edit to my question if that helps? I presume it's the browser build(?) that is important?

Comment: just to add there is also a copy of the image in the base `www/img` path.

Comment: so you aren't using Android as platform ? I updated my answer with a possible solution

Comment: yes sorry I did include  one similar to that but with src="" instead of value but changing it to value worked for me. What is the reason for this and why is it different?

Comment: It's because it's a `<preference>` for the browser platform it's not like the `<splash>`. I imagine you have to define this for the browser because the Android, iOS, etc. have a fixed path to where to find the image resources.

Comment: That's very useful to know. Thank you for your help!